# If a ghost cleans a vent with an impostor in it, does the impostor get kicked out of the vent?

Tags: among-us

If a ghost performs their clean vent task on a vent that an impostor is sitting in, does the impostor get kicked out of the vent for a passer-by or a camera to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just tried this with friends. If you're a ghost, cleaning a vent with an impostor in it does nothing; it doesn't block the impostor for venting, and it doesn't pop the impostor out.